# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81 I

Tags: python, robotframework

I imported 81 all version in my project but still not resolve and getting same error

Comment: What library are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

To use browser automation capabilities, please check 3 things are aligned:

1. Your browser version(go to chrome>Help>Check version)
2. Download Chrome Driver for the same version from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
3. pip freeze and check the selenium version and seleniumlibrary versions.